# 2D vector resize in class. Error was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, vector

edit: Sorry about that, I put in the wrong vector.  And this is the non working code.  The line 'stage_4.resize(20, vector(20, 0));' is giving me the error.  'stage_4.resize(20); works, but I couldn't get it to compile by adjusting both dimensions.  Also, I forgot to mention I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 and Mingw32-gcc.

I'm relatively new to c++ and have basically learned by reading tutorials on the internet so there are some pretty big gaps in my understanding of it.  I've been trying to write a program using more classes to make things more streamlined and just started looking into using vectors.  However, I've hit a bit of a snag in the combination of the two.  I've created a class, and made a vector within it.  It all compiles fine until I try to resize the vector as a 2 dimensional array within a function of the class.  Here's the relevant code.

```
class stage{
public:
std::vector<int> stage_4;

   int setup(int a){
      switch (a){
      case 1:
         stage_4.resize(20, vector<int>(20, 0));
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

When I just do stage_4.resize(20); It compiles no problem.  But when I try to change both dimensions of the array, like in this code, it tells me "error: 'vector' was not declared in this scope".  I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong since, as I said, I'm fairly new to c++.

edit: I also tried to do stage_4.resize(20, std::vector(20,0));, but then it tells me "no matching function for call to 'std::vector::resize(int, std::vector)'"

Comment: Looks like you forgot to use `std::` in front of `vector<int>(20, 0)`

Comment: Your own example code contains the solution.... the weird thing is, these kind of posts are getting more frequent lately.

Comment: @CannGramps   I do not see anywhere in your code a declaration of         stage_4. What is it?

Comment: *"I'm relatively new to c++ and have basically learned by reading tutorials on the internet so there are some pretty big gaps in my understanding of it."* - Then you should probably read a book.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath They are frequent because people answer them :-P

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm probably the most avid question closer here so please address that to someone else :P This is not an MCVE...

Comment: So you showed us the working code, but not the non-working code that you need help with? lol...

Answer (score 2):

It's `std::vector`.

`vector` lives in the `std` namespace.